# PHP delete key value pairs from array that have empty value

Tags: php, arrays

I have post data that looks like this:

```
array(2) { 
    ["ui"]=> array(1) { 
        ["menu"]=> array(3) { 
            ["button1"]=> string(8) "Press me" 
            ["button2"]=> string(9) "Tickle me"
            ["button3"]=> string(0) ""

        }
    }
    ["messages"]=> array(1) { 
        ["status"]=> array(2) { 
            ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["success"]=> string(0) ""
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove all key, value pairs that have an empty value to get a result like this:

```
 array(1) { 
    ["ui"]=> array(1) { 
        ["menu"]=> array(2) { 
            ["button1"]=> string(8) "Press me" 
            ["button2"]=> string(9) "Tickle me"
        }
    }
}
```

So I implemented this recursive function:

```
function clear_empty_array_values($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            clear_empty_array_values($value);  
        }else{
            if (empty($value)){
                unset($array[$key]);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call this function on my array:

```
clear_empty_array_values($my_array);
```

I get the same result as before calling the method.

Can you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify `$my_array` in place as you show, you need to pass-by-reference `&`.  Then to modify `$value` in the `foreach` use a reference `&`:

```
function clear_empty_array_values(&$array){
    foreach($array as $key => &$value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            clear_empty_array_values($value);
        }
        if(empty($value)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Added & to both the $array parameter and the $value variable, but it still shows the same for me, maybe is the array I send in that is wrong, updated my post with the actual data it gets. Sorry for the edit!

Comment: Ok now it works! Needed to remove the else so it removed empty arrays as well

Comment: OK, the logic looked sound but it would not remove the top-most array if empty.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Do this one: 
function clear_empty_array_values(&$array)

or, you must return value:

```
function clear_empty_array_values($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $array[$key] = clear_empty_array_values($value);  
        }else{
            if (empty($value)){
                unset($array[$key]);
            }  
        }
    }
return $array;
}
```